# How Might I Extract Specific Characters From A String Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

**Question**: Consider the following string, s, which is equal to:

```
\\xxxxxx.com\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\04. xxx\02. xxx\B. xxxx\yyy
```

What code might be used in order for PlaceHolderIndex to have the value "**04.02.B**" ?

Comment: `Split` should be a good start.

Comment: @BigBen Would the backslashes act as the delimter fot the split function ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: for the first split on the backslash, then split on the `.` and test whether there is a second, if so concatenate the first.

Comment: Is the string always the same length? If so, you could just extract characters 42-43, 50-51, and 58-59.

Comment: @JoshEller no it is not. I think I have it following BigBen's suggestion using the Split function.

Comment: You need to come up with a set of rules that unambiguously defines exactly what you want to do. Then it is usually easy to create code.  Applying @ScottCraner rule without modification, you would return the `xxxxxx.04.02.B`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld could you elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a small VBA function that accepts a string, splits it using "\" as a separator, ignores the first part ("\xxxxxxx.com\"), then looks for "." in each of the sections, and concatenates the data before the ".".

```
Function fGetData(strInput As String) As String
    Dim aData() As String
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    aData = Split(strInput, "\")
    For lngLoop1 = 3 To UBound(aData) ' ignore the first 3 elements as they are "\\xxxxx.com\"
        If InStr(aData(lngLoop1), ".") > 0 Then
            fGetData = fGetData & Left(aData(lngLoop1), InStr(aData(lngLoop1), "."))
        End If
    Next lngLoop1
    If Right(fGetData, 1) = "." Then fGetData = Left(fGetData, Len(fGetData) - 1)
End Function
```

Regards,